# How to add quotation marks to substrings of interest only?

Tags: python, string

I have written a parser that is able to attribute information from a string. I don't know how to add quotation marks around substrings of interest. Let me illustrate:

I've got this message:

```
message = 'I have two variables: -mass: 12 --vel= 18 OR this is just another descriptor AND that new thing OR that newfangled thing'
```

That I need to add quotation marks around specific substrings (that follow boolean operators) like this:

```
message = 'I have two variables: -mass: 12 --vel= 18 OR "this is just another descriptor" AND "that new thing" OR "that newfangled thing"'
```

I've done this:

```
attributes = ['OR', 'AND', 'NOT']
message = 'I have two variables: -mass: 12 --vel= 18 OR this is just another descriptor AND that new thing OR that new fangled thing'
for attribute in attributes:
        modified_attribute = ' '+attribute+' '
        message = modified_attribute.join('"{}"'.format(s.strip()) for s in message.split(attribute))
        if attributes.index(attribute)>0: message = message[1:-1]

print(message)
```

However, it returns this, which is not what I want:

```
"I have two variables: -mass: 12 --vel= 18" OR "this is just another descriptor" AND "that new thing" OR "that new fangled thing"
```

The above should have quotation marks around the first sentence, as it was not preceded by a boolean operator. What do I do?

EDIT:
I am looking for a scalable solution which can be used to quote any number of substrings within a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with lookahead like this:

```
import re
message = re.sub(r'(\b(?:{0})\b) (.*?)(?=\s*\b(?:{0}|$)\b)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, attributes))), r'\1 "\2"', message)
```

`message` will become:

```
I have two variables: -mass: 12 --vel= 18 OR "this is just another descriptor" AND "that new thing" OR "that new fangled thing"
```

Comment: Your solution is very clever, but it doesn't seem to be scalable - for instance, if I increased the number of boolean statements to 4 or reduced them down to 1, then the code doen't seem to work. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try it? It definitely works no matter how many Boolean statements there are. See the demo here (click on the `run` button): https://repl.it/repls/RadiantScarceSequences

Comment: I did, I'm using VisualCode editor (Python ver 3.5.6). For instance, I modified the message like this: message = 'I have two variables: -mass: 12 --vel= 18 OR this is just another descriptor AND that new thing OR that new fangled thing AND how about this?' There are no quotes past the last boolean operator.

Answer (score 0):

blhsing's solution seems quite robust. But if you want to play with some "from- scratch" data structure to solve the problem, below is an example of using a linked-list. Each node contains an attribute (logical operator in your case), a fraction of the original message and a reference to its next node.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, message, attr):
        self.message = message
        self.attr = attr
        self.next = None

    def add_next(self, message, attr):

        if self.is_end:
            self.set_next( Node(message, attr) )
        else:
            dummy = Node(message, attr)
            dummy.set_next(self.next)
            self.set_next(dummy)

        return None

    def split(self, attr):
        (self.message, _, new_message) = self.message.partition(attr)

        if len(new_message) > 0:
            self.add_next(new_message, attr)

        if not self.is_end:
            self.next.split(attr)

        return None

    def join_quoted_from_here(self):
        res = ''
        dummy = self

        while True:
            if dummy.is_head:
                res += dummy.message
            else:
                res += (dummy.attr + dummy.quoted)

            if dummy.is_end: break
            dummy = dummy.next

        return res

    def join_original_from_here(self):
        res = ''
        dummy = self

        while True:
            if dummy.is_head:
                res += dummy.message
            else:
                res += (dummy.attr + dummy.message)

            if dummy.is_end: break
            dummy = dummy.next

        return res

    @property
    def quoted(self):
        return ' "{}" '.format( self.message.strip() )

    @property
    def is_end(self):
        return self.next is None

    @property
    def is_head(self):
        return False

    def set_next(self, node):
        self.next = node


class HeadNode(Node):

    @property
    def is_end(self):
        return False

    @property
    def is_head(self):
        return True


class Message:

    def __init__(self, message, attrs):
        self.head = HeadNode(message, attrs[0])
        self.head.split(attrs[0])
        for attr in attrs[1:]:
            self.head.split(attr)

        return None

    @property
    def quoted(self):
        return self.head.join_quoted_from_here()

    @property
    def original(self):
        return self.head.join_original_from_here()


attributes = ['OR', 'AND', 'NOT']
message = ('I have two variables: -mass: 12 --vel= 18 OR this is just another'
          ' descriptor AND that new thing OR that new fangled thing')

mes = Message(message, attributes)

print(mes.quoted)
```

I think the construction of the linked list takes approximately O(mN), where m is the number of separators. Please correct it if it's not. And the reassembling takes O(N_splits). If you need to frequently output the quoted result, you can just store it as a static data member of Message. But that will take more space. Have fun!

#### Performance

```
t1 = timeit.timeit(linked_list, number=100000) # 1.398024505993817
t2 = timeit.timeit(sol_blhsing, number=100000) # 1.5282143959921086
```

The linked-list is slightly faster than blhsing's solution in your very case!